# How to build a dataframe from an (empty) vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, empty-list

The code snippet below converts a pair of vectors to a data frame, filling in along the way one column to indicate the provenance ("State") and another to indicate the type ("Ingredient").

```
overflow  <- setdiff(c(21, 23, 27), c(21, 23))
underflow <- setdiff(c(11, 13, 17), c(17))

dfo <- data.frame("State"="over", Value=overflow)
dfu <- data.frame("State"="under", Value=underflow)
df <- rbind(dfo, dfu)

df$Ingredient <- "Beans"
```

With the given data all is well. We get the following dataframe.

```
> df
  State Value Ingredient
1  over    27      Beans
2 under    11      Beans
3 under    13      Beans
```

But this is not good enough for the boundary case when `setdiff` produces an empty vector (e.g.: `underflow <- setdiff(c(11, 13, 17), c(11, 13, 17))`.

How can I build a dataframe from a vector while handling the case of an empty vector? The option of carrying around a "data frame is empty" flag would be a bad one since the code would become peppered with `if` statements.

**Update**

In lieu of a comment to @AndS.'s suggestion:

Replacing `data.frame` with `dplyr::data_frame` works well. Initially at least. But inserting a column remains problematic. If both `overflow` and `underflow` are empty lists, `df$Ingredient <- "Beans"` fails.

Comment: try `dplyr::data_frame`  instead of `data.frame` This will make zero observation dataframes instead of throwing errors.

Comment: Using `library(data.table)`, you can initialize something as `dt <- data.table(State = character(), Value = numeric(), Ingredient = character())` works fine. Alternatively, empty `data.table` would inherit names from the arguments you listed above since the R object type is passed along.

Comment: @AndS. Your solution almost works. I updated the question.

Comment: Not a problem, stick with dplyr and instead of `df$Ingredient <- "Beans"`, assign the variable in `mutate`. For example: `df <- rbind(dfo, dfu) %>% mutate(Ingredient = "Beans")` this will still make you a zero observation dataframe , but now with an extra column and no errors. If there is any observations, "beans" will be added to the new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr::data_frame` is probably the best option, but here's a base R approach just for fun

```
flow <- list(over  = setdiff(c(21, 23, 27), c(21, 23)),
             under = setdiff(c(11, 13, 17), c(17)))


flow.df <- Map(function(State, x) 
                if(length(x)) data.frame(State, x, Ingredient = 'Beans')
               , names(flow)
               , flow)

df <- do.call(rbind, flow.df)

df

#         State  x Ingredient
# over     over 27      Beans
# under.1 under 11      Beans
# under.2 under 13      Beans
```

When one of them is empty:

```
flow <- list(over  = setdiff(c(21, 23, 21), c(21, 23)),
             under = setdiff(c(11, 13, 17), c(17)))


flow.df <- Map(function(State, x) 
                if(length(x)) data.frame(State, x, Ingredient = 'Beans')
               , names(flow)
               , flow)

df <- do.call(rbind, flow.df)

df

#         State  x Ingredient
# under.1 under 11      Beans
# under.2 under 13      Beans
```

Using `dplyr::data_frame` and `dplyr::mutate` as suggested by @AndS. lets you avoid the `if` statement:

```
library(dplyr)

flow <- list(over  = setdiff(c(21, 23, 21), c(21, 23)),
             under = setdiff(c(11, 13, 17), c(17)))


flow.df <- Map(function(State, x) data_frame(State, x)
               , names(flow)
               , flow)

df <- do.call(rbind, flow.df)

df %>% mutate(Ingredient = 'Beans')

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   State     x Ingredient
# * <chr> <dbl> <chr>     
# 1 under  11.0 Beans     
# 2 under  13.0 Beans
```

Another commenter, who has since deleted their comment, pointed out you can use `rep` with `times = length(x)` where `x` is `overflow` or `underflow`

```
flow <- list(over  = setdiff(c(21, 23, 21), c(21, 23)),
             under = setdiff(c(11, 13, 17), c(17)))


flow.df <- Map(function(State, x, len) 
                data.frame(State = rep(State, len)
                           , x
                           , Ingredient = rep('Beans', len))
               , names(flow)
               , flow
               , lengths(flow))

df <- do.call(rbind, flow.df)

df

#         State  x Ingredient
# under.1 under 11      Beans
# under.2 under 13      Beans
```

Comment: Hey @Ryan, do you want to throw in the `data_frame` example for completeness?

Comment: @Ryan All nice suggestions. dplyr's is cleanest, but you removed a part (adding a column to an empty data_frame) that remains problematic. I updated the question.